# Possible for SQL stored procedure to call .NET object?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Is it possible for a SQL Stored Procedure to call a .NET object?  In my situation, I need to take a string parameter and return a hashed result that can be consumed by my secure client.

I can either have this SP called on a per result basis (once per row), or I can possibly return multiple rows.  It all depends on what SQL will support me doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 introduced CLR into the server. This allows you to write .NET functions and call them from within SQL Server stored procedures.

Read [this howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k.aspx) on how to create and use CLR within SQL Server.

This will work in SQL Server 2005 and above.

Comment: What happens to the assembly after I deploy it?  Where does it go? (is it still needed on the file system?)

Comment: @MakerOfThings7 - As far as I know it is held within SQL Server. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dahcx0ww.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can write sql stored procedure in C# by using [Sql Clr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136%28SQL.90%29.aspx) which will allow to call .Net object.